# Excel 365 Can't Update Link

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

I'm on Office 365.
I'm working on many xlsx files (12 files) linked each together.

Every time I open a specific file, a window pops up saying: This workbook contains one or more links that cannot be updated.
Continue - Edit Links..

If I click Edit Links I see all links with OK status.
If I click Continue everything works but I'd like to Autoupdate that link.

That problem happened ONLY with Excel 2016 and Excel 2019, not in Excel 2013.

I tried to follow these instructions but it doesn't work:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/control-when-external-references-links-are-updated-21e995b5-bab1-4328-8ab3-dd357fe0e653

I really don't know how to update links and block that popup

Comment: Please provide more information on your Office 365.  Why do you have Excel installed twice?  By having Office 365 installed you have the most recent version of Excel installed also.

Comment: I had Excel 2013, with that version all files opened regularly but there were big problems with speed. I uninstalled excel 2013 and put the latest version of excel. With this I have no problems with speed but this problem remains

Comment: Your question, as it's currently written, is confusing.  You should clarify it by editing it.

Comment: You right Ramhound, edited

Answer (score -1):

Correction and edit:

unable to comment under original post so I will put it here. After rereading your issue, I would put attention to what other comments pointed out- you had two office installations at one point.

Even if you uninstalled office 2013 afterwards, it's very common that office experiences issues if a version was installed along another one. I suggest a repair on office 365 and thorough one at that. I believe that would be the online repair and not the quick repair.

1. right click start menu
2. click on *'Apps & Features'* (assuming you are using windows 10)
3. click on *Microsoft Office 365*
4. Click on *Modify*
5. Click on *Online Repair*
6. Check if issue persists

Comment: I tried but it doesn't works.
I checked "Automatic Updates" and "Don't display the alert and update links" in Startup Prompt but it doesn't works.

Error message is: this workbook contains one or more links that cannot be updated.

Comment: try a repair on office 365

Comment: Done but nothing happened

Comment: UPDATE:



I check Broken Links on every Workbook (with KooTools and OfficeTab) and there aren't any Broken links.. anyway this error still popup

Comment: Any news? How can i fix?